# how to redirect output, running octave under windows

Tags: octave

I would like to redirect the output of an octave script, eg `myscript.m > myoutput.mat`
Anyone know how to do this?  I am running octave under Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had a similar problem.
There are two ways to accomplish this.

1. The obvious one that doesn't necessarily work
   on what_i_want_to_print.m

   ```
   function what_i_want_to_print()
     disp("hello world");
   end
   ```

   Then from the command prompt execute:

   ```
   C:/Octave/bin/octave-cli.exe --eval "what_i_want_to_print()">filename.txt
   ```
2. You can also save all the outputs directly from Octave with the [diary](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Diary-and-Echo-Commands.html) function:

   ```
   octave:1>> diary(FILENAME.TXT);
   octave:2>> what_i_want_to_print();
   octave:3>> diary off;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

From the extension "mat" of the target file, I guess you want to save some kind of numerical objects, if it's true, you can use save() command.

```
save("-mat", "myoutput.mat", "A", "B")
```

would save A and B to myoutput.mat in Matlab format.

Run `doc save` in the Octave console to get more information.